# How to install TLS certificates on pods where Java is deployed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes

How can I install certificates on pods or servers where Java code is deployed?

Comment: Please provide additional details. What kind of certificates do you have? What is the target environment? Is this an application or a web site? Is it running within a container or natively?  Are the certificates for specific environments (i.e. development, staging, production, etc)?

Answer (score -1):

There's two ways:

1. *(Perhaps not what you're looking for)* Use AWS Application Load Balancer and AWS Certificate Manager to terminal TLS. This is done by creating `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` with annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: ...` (and some others). *Note that you can't access the ACM private key, so this doesn't work if you want to terminate TLS in Java.*
2. Use [`cert-mananager`](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager) to generate a certificate with Let's Encrypt or another supported service. Create an `Issuer` and then create a `Certificate` and a `Secret` to store its private key in the appropriate namespace. Then you can reference the Secret in your pods and load them in Java.

If you go the second route but would like to have a single certificate that is reused across namespaces, then you have to use something like [`syncator`](https://github.com/almson/synator/) to replicate the Secrets across namespaces.